# Remove a green line appearing dead middle on my monitor

Tags: display, stuck-pixel

A green line has started appearing on my monitor.

[image: green line on screen]

Whenever I start my computer it's there. But only twice it managed to disappear by itself but only after four or five hours of usage.

Is there any way to remove it?

Answer (score 4):

This is definitely a hardware issue with your monitor.

Your next step should be to immediately contact the manufacturer to check the warranty status and, if possible get them to repair or replace it. There's not really much else you can do unfortunately.

I had a similar problem with an HP 2509m. They ended up replacing it with a refurbished unit- it wasn't possible for HP to economically repair it.

If you attempt a repair and something goes wrong, then you risk voiding the warranty. This is one of those times when your best bet is getting the manufacturer involved before reaching for the screwdriver yourself.

Comment: more precisely, I suspect a connector is loose, but just barely

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean my "connector"? Something inside the screen itself, or the VGA/DVI cable?

Comment: My guess would be the LVDS connector in the screen

Comment: "Usually you only get stuck pixels." That means nothing, except there another problem exists that is more common. "something has gone awry in a driver". A driver problem? Ok, well the OP can prove that's not happening in 5 seconds by simply shutting down his PC and continuing to enjoy the green line. A driver problem!

Comment: @Dan Warranty has gone now. I'm now on my own.

(A)FiascoLabs actually my camera is awful. That line may seem as a bit broad but its actually as thin as this cursor with which I'm typing now. I don't think I have pixels stuck.

(A)Dan, This line appears as soon as I press power button of my computer. Even before the first beep.

I'll try putting both cables of my monitor out and in. However I've done it before. Thanks for all your answers.

Comment: You've probably seen this thread about other LCDs with a single vertical green line of pixels already: http://www.avsforum.com/t/1384788/stumped-samsung-pn50b650s1-vertical-green-line-of-single-pixels-why. The reason it appears as soon as your PC turns on is simply because the monitor was in power saving mode up until that point. If you disconnect the signal cable from your monitor (when the PC is on) you'll still see the green line on the screen for a few seconds before the monitor goes on standby.

Comment: @Dan What do you mean by "power saving mode"? I just have setting to put the monitor asleep after 5 minutes of no use. I don't have any power saving mode. BTW I tried your saying and yes I still see green line (which I already know will be there) with message "check your signal cable". I don't know after that monitor goes in power saving mode. I never seen it. Though this is strange problem. I again seen it disappeared as I was sitting for 2.5 hours. I think this is some kinda monitor defect which can only be resolved by repairing it.